# Assertion Failed: You tried to load all records but you have no adapter

Tags: ember.js, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Using

> DEBUG: -------------------------------
>   DEBUG: Ember      : 1.5.1
>   DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.3.0
>   DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.10.2
>   DEBUG: -------------------------------

I get error:

Error while loading route: Error: Assertion Failed: You tried to load all records but you have no adapter (for story)

Trying to update the repo found in this [tutorial](http://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/setting-up-an-ember-app-with-a-rails-backend) to latest ember install.

[Repo with my updates](https://github.com/barberj/ember-data-rails-example/tree/ember_1_5_1)

I have defined my store (app/assets/javascript/store.js.coffee) like

> App.Store = DS.Store.extend
>     adapter: '-active-model'
>     namespace: 'api/v1'

Answer (score 0):

Defining the store/adapter in this fashion is deprecated since 1.0 beta 1, you should upgrade to at least 1.0 beta 7.  The adapter(s) should be defined like this now:

Site Wide:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api/v1'
});
```

Model Specific:

```
App.PostAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter;

App.DogAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend({
  host: 'www.foo.com'
});
```

More details can be found in the transition document

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

Comment: When i use the site wide definition i get this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined

I feel the problem is that i'm not seeing Ember Data in the console, but i was under the impression that the gem would handle all that.

Answer (score 0):

It appears if i download v1.0.0-beta.7 of ember-data and put it in the vendor directory along with the changes above it works